# iPhone Simulator no longer running app at 4inch resolution

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ios-simulator

All throughout development my app has been running fine in the simulator on both the 3.5 and 4 inch screens. However, when I finally added Icons and Launch Images to the app the 4inch simulator no longer works. It runs the app in 3.5inch res with black bars at the top and bottom. It works fine running on my actual iPhone 5 so I think this is a bug with the simulator. Anyone else experienced this, and know a fix?

Regards, 
Mike

Comment: Sometimes it is a good idear to clear the project and re-build it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing the `Default-568h@2x.png` Launch Image, if it is included in your project make sure that it is also included in you target.

Comment: What you could do is remove the splash screen images you added to the project, and drag and drop them on the correct spot on the "summary" tab (when you select the project in the left bar, select your target and go to "summary"). You will be sure they are named correctly.

Comment: I have included the Default-568h@2x.png.

Comment: Have you checked that if the `Default-568h@2x.png` is in the tager, also check the summary tag in the project as [rdurand](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1503967/rdurand) mentioned.

Comment: Right, I figured it out. We were on the right lines. By mistake I hadn't capitalised the 'd'. Xcode's summary tab still showed the file as a launch image, but the simulator was messing up! Thanks for the help guys.